# C++ How to create a dynamic array of vectors?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, vector, std

I'm having problem initialising an array of std::vectors.

I'm declaring and initialising it like this:

```
vector<component_change*>* _changes;
_changes = new vector<component_change*> [numThreads];
```

in the hope that it's in the same form as this:

```
int * foo;
foo = new int [5];
```

but when I hit a breakpoint after the initialisation, _changes' size is 0.
What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

I don't want to use a vector of vectors as the number I need remains constant throughout the program but depends on the current hardware. And I'm not just looking for a single vector (Each vector will be used by a different thread then merged when the threads have finished their tasks).

Thanks guys! :)

Comment: "constant throughout the program but depends on the current hardware" how about a `std::array<>`?

Comment: @awesomeyi Thanks I'll have a look :)

Comment: @awesomeyi Sorry, I don't think that's what i was looking for really. I use thread::hardware_concurrency() to get the number of cores then create a new array of that size, which i don't think i can pass into std::array<>. or can i?

Comment: @NeilKirk: Unless it's several components per thread, in which case it's `std::vector<std::vector<component_change>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the size can be determined at compile time use a [std::array](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/).  If the size is a run-time argument then use a vector and don't change the size of the container.

Comment: I'm looking at this atm.

Comment: Thanks, This worked. I was worried about performance with a vector but if i'm not changing it it shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is correct. But you misinterpreted the debugger. _changes's size is not 0, but the first vector in your array (the one _changes points at) is empty. Thats because the debugger does not know if _changes points at a single element or an array (in that case the compiler would not know how many elements are in that array). Simply use a vector and call [std::vector::shrink_to_fit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/shrink_to_fit/).

Answer (score 0):

Are you interested in have a vector for each thread, or a vector containing items used by each thread? I assumed the later, but my answer could be adapted.

This is using a statically sized array; (this syntax is close).

```
const int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 5;
component_change* _changes[NUMBER_OF_THREADS] =
{
  new component_change(1),
  new component_change(2),
  new component_change(3),
  new component_change(4),
  new component_change(5)
}
```

If the number of threads is dynamic, you will have to use a new...

```
int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = system.getThreadCount();
component_change* _changes = new component_change[NUMBER_OF_THREADS];

for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++)
{
  _changes[i] = new component_change(i+1);
}
```

If you want to a std::vector:

```
 int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = system.getThreadCount();
std::vector<component_change*> _changes;
_changes.reserve(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);

for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++)
{
  _changes.push_back(new component_change(i+1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're kind of mislead, this **size** that you are reading belongs to the **vector** in the first element of the array. Its size is equal to 0 since no elements have been inserted in the **vector** yet.

Answer (score 0):

`new vector` is usually wrong.

You should use, with most preferred if possible first,

```
std::vector<component_change> _changes(numThreads);
```

or

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<component_change>> _changes(numThreads);
```

or

```
std::vector<component_change*> _changes(numThreads);
```

or if each element of the vector should itself contain an array of components (it's not clear in your question)

```
std::vector<std::vector<**component_change**>> _changes(numThreads);
```

Declaring the component as one of the above ways, depending on your needs.

Note that the pointers begin not pointing to anything. You'd have to allocate the individual components as a separate step.

The following creates an array of numThreads vectors, not a vector of numThread elements.

```
new vector<component_change*> [numThreads]
```

Comment: Yes and the last bit you wrote is what I need. Thanks